# Ansible: How to check multiple servers for a text file value, to decide which servers to run the script on?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to ask Ansible to check if a server is passive or active based on the value of a specific file in each server, then Ansible will decide which server it runs the next script on.

For example with 2 servers:

**Server1**

```
cat /tmp/currentstate
PASSIVE
```

**Server2**

```
cat /tmp/currentstate 
ACTIVE
```

**In Ansible**

Trigger next set of jobs on server where the output was `ACTIVE`.

Once the jobs complete, trigger next set of jobs on server where output was `PASSIVE`

What I have done so far to grab the state, and output the value to Ansible is

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ hostname1 | mandatory }}"
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Grab state of first server
    shell: |
      cat {{ ans_script_path }}currentstate.log
    register: state_server1

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ state_server1.stdout }}"

- hosts: "{{ hostname2 | mandatory }}"
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Grab state of second server
    shell: |
      cat {{ ans_script_path }}currentstate.log
    register: state_server2

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ state_server2.stdout }}"
```

What I have done so far to trigger the script

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ active_hostname | mandatory }}"
  tasks:
  - name: Run the shutdown on active server first
    shell: sh {{ ans_script_path }}stopstart_terracotta_main.sh shutdown
    register: run_result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ run_result.stdout }}"

- hosts: "{{ passive_hostname | mandatory }}"
  tasks:
  - name: Run the shutdown on passive server first
    shell: sh {{ ans_script_path }}stopstart_terracotta_main.sh shutdown
    register: run_result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ run_result.stdout }}"
```

but I don't know how to set the value of `active_hostname` & `passive_hostname` based on the value from the script above.

How can I set the Ansible variable of `active_hostname` & `passive_hostname` based on the output of the first section?

Comment: Hi @ZmirBurger, did any of the answers help?

Answer (score 0):

A better solution came to my mind is to include hosts in new groups according to their state.
This would be more optimal in case there are more than two hosts.

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    ans_script_path: /tmp/
  tasks:
  - name: Grab state of server
    shell: |
        cat {{ ans_script_path }}currentstate.log
    register: server_state

  - add_host:
      hostname: "{{ item }}"
      # every host will be added to a new group according to its state
      groups: "{{ 'active' if hostvars[item].server_state.stdout == 'ACTIVE' else 'passive' }}"
      # Shorter, but the new groups will be in capital letters
      # groups: "{{ hostvars[item].server_state.stdout }}"
    loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"  
    changed_when: false

  - name: show the groups the host(s) are in
    debug:
      msg: "{{ group_names }}"

- hosts: active
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Run the shutdown on active server first
    shell: hostname -f # changed that for debugging
    register: run_result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ run_result.stdout }}"

- hosts: passive
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Run the shutdown on passive server first
    shell: hostname -f
    register: run_result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ run_result.stdout }}"
```

`test-001` is `PASSIVE`
`test-002` is `ACTIVE`

```yaml
PLAY [all] ***************************************************************

TASK [Grab state of server] **********************************************
ok: [test-002]
ok: [test-001]

TASK [add_host] **********************************************************
ok: [test-001] => (item=test-001)
ok: [test-001] => (item=test-002)

TASK [show the groups the host(s) are in] ********************************
ok: [test-001] => {
    "msg": [
        "passive"
    ]
}
ok: [test-002] => {
    "msg": [
        "active"
    ]
}

PLAY [active] *************************************************************

TASK [Run the shutdown on active server first] ****************************
changed: [test-002]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************
ok: [test-002] => {
    "msg": "test-002"
}

PLAY [passive] ************************************************************

TASK [Run the shutdown on passive server first] ****************************
changed: [test-001]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************
ok: [test-001] => {
    "msg": "test-001"
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************
test-001 : ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test-002 : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, given two remote hosts

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /tmp/currentstate.log
ACTIVE

shell> ssh admin@test_13 cat /tmp/currentstate.log
PASSIVE
```

The playbook below reads the files and runs the commands on active and passive servers

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: "{{ host1 }},{{ host2 }}"
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    server_states: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                            zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                                map('extract', hostvars, ['server_state', 'stdout'])|
                                list)) }}"
    server_active: "{{ server_states|dict2items|
                                     selectattr('value', 'eq', 'ACTIVE')|
                                     map(attribute='key')|list }}"
    server_pasive: "{{ server_states|dict2items|
                                     selectattr('value', 'eq', 'PASSIVE')|
                                     map(attribute='key')|list }}"
  tasks:
    - command: cat /tmp/currentstate.log
      register: server_state
    - debug:
        var: server_state.stdout
    - block:
        - debug:
            var: server_states
        - debug:
            var: server_active
        - debug:
            var: server_pasive
      run_once: true
    - command: echo 'Shutdown active server'
      register: out_active
      delegate_to: "{{ server_active.0 }}"
    - command: echo 'Shutdown passive server'
      register: out_pasive
      delegate_to: "{{ server_pasive.0 }}"
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ server_active.0 }}: [{{ out_active.stdout }}]  {{ out_active.start }}
          {{ server_pasive.0 }}: [{{ out_pasive.stdout }}] {{ out_pasive.start }}
      run_once: true
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e host1=test_11 -e host2=test_13

PLAY [test_11,test_13] ***********************************************************************

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [test_13]
changed: [test_11]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  server_state.stdout: ACTIVE
ok: [test_13] => 
  server_state.stdout: PASSIVE

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  server_states:
    test_11: ACTIVE
    test_13: PASSIVE

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  server_active:
  - test_11

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  server_pasive:
  - test_13

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [test_11]
changed: [test_13 -> test_11]

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [test_11 -> test_13]
changed: [test_13]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: |-
    test_11: [Shutdown active server]  2022-10-27 11:16:00.766309
    test_13: [Shutdown passive server] 2022-10-27 11:16:02.501907

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=8    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=4    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 0):

From the description of your use case I understand that you like to perform tasks on certain servers which a have service role installed (annot.: [Terracotta Server](https://github.com/terracotta-oss)) and based on a certain service state.

Therefore, I like to recommend an approach with [Custom facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#adding-custom-facts).

Depending on if you have control about where the `currentstate.log` is placed or how it is structured, you could use in example something like

```bash
 cat /tmp/ansible/service/terracotta.fact
```

```ini
[currentstate]
ACTIVE = true
PASSIVE = false
```

> *or add dynamic facts by adding executable scripts to `facts.d` ...*

Means, alternatively, you can add the current service state to your host facts by creating and running a script in `facts.d`, which would just read the content of `/tmp/currentstate.log`.

Then, a sample playbook like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false

  gather_facts: true
  fact_path: /tmp/ansible/service
  gather_subset:
    - "!all"
    - "!min"
    - "local"

  tasks:

  - name: Show Gathered Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts }}"
    when: ansible_local.terracotta.currentstate.active | bool
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show Gathered Facts] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    ansible_local:
      terracotta:
        currentstate:
          active: 'true'
          passive: 'false'
    gather_subset:
    - '!all'
    - '!min'
    - local
    module_setup: true
```

---

An other approach is to address [How the inventory is build](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-setup-examples) and [Group the hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-setup-examples)

```ini
[terracotta:children]
terracotta_active
terracotta_passive

[terracotta_active]
terracotta1.example.com

[terracotta_passive]
terracotta2.example.com
```

You can then just easily and simple define where a playbook or task should run, just by [Targeting hosts and groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#patterns-targeting-hosts-and-groups)

```bash
ansible-inventory -i hosts--graph
@all:
  |--@terracotta:
  |  |--@terracotta_active:
  |  |  |--terracotta1.example.com
  |  |--@terracotta_passive:
  |  |  |--terracotta2.example.com
  |--@ungrouped:

ansible-inventory -i hosts terracotta_active --graph
@terracotta_active:
  |--terracotta1.example.com
```

or [Conditionals based on `ansible_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts), in example

```yaml
when: 'terracotta_active' in group_names
```

---

<sub>*... from my understanding, both would be minimal and simple solutions without re-implementing functionality which seems to be already there.*</sub>